# AI accepted Xamarin solution fails to activate Speakerphone on Android 13

Tags: android, xamarin

I developed this while Chatting with Bing AI. This failed to activate Speakerphone on Android 13 but works on Android 10. So I asked AI why this is not working and it said that Android documents supports this and should work. I tried this on Google Pixel and LG phones.

Any suggestion?

namespace ActivateSpeaker
{
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class Receiver1 : BroadcastReceiver
{
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
var state = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraState);
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
if (intent.Action == TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged)
{
if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateOffhook)
{
Task.Run(() =>
{
Task.Delay(5000).Wait();

```
                    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S)
                    {
                        AudioDeviceInfo speakerDevice = null;
                        IList<AudioDeviceInfo> devices = audioManager.AvailableCommunicationDevices;
                        foreach (AudioDeviceInfo device in devices)
                        {
                            if (device.Type == AudioDeviceType.BuiltinSpeaker)
                            {
                                speakerDevice = device;
                                var IsItTrue = audioManager.SetCommunicationDevice(speakerDevice);
                                audioManager.Mode = Mode.InCall;
                                audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = true;
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle)
            {
                //audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: AI won't always give you a true answer. It seems that there is an android issue with this functionality https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279105862

Comment: Three years ago I reported this to Google as my Pixel automatically upgraded to Android 11 and stop activating the speakerphone. Their solution was to send me replacement Android 10 Pixel which I still use while blocking it from upgrading to latest Android. The problem with their soultion is that I am stuck with Android 10. This significantly compromise my Security that would be addressed by latest Android. My latest communication is going on deaf ears and they are asking me to post the question here. So far my posting attempts have not resulted into ANY working solution!!!!!!